Proving the generalized product rule by induction
I am trying to show that $(\prod_{i=1}^{n} {f_i})' = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[f_i'\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^{n}f_j]$.
This holds true for n = 2. $(f_1f_2)' = f_1'f_2 + f_2'f_1.$
Our inductive hypothesis is $(\prod_{i=1}^{k} {f_i})' = \sum_{i=1}^{k}[f_i'\prod_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\neq i}}^{k}f_j]$.
We must show that $(\prod_{i=1}^{k+1} {f_i})' = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}[f_i'\prod_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\neq i}}^{k+1}f_j]$.
We break up the left side into $((\prod_{i=1}^{k} {f_i})f_{k+1})'$.
By the product rule for two functions, this equals $(\sum_{i=1}^{k}[f_i'\prod_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\neq i}}^{k}f_j])(f_{k+1}) +(f_{k+1})'(\prod_{i=1}^{k} f_i)$
Does anyone have tips for turning the right-hand side into $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}[f_i'\prod_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\neq i}}^{k+1}f_j]$? Also, does anyone have tips on my proof structure? Thank you in advance.

This question is similar to: The derivative of a product of more than two functions. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search.
